# Move Mail item in Outlook with Python

Tags: python, outlook

I try to move a message from one Folder in Outlook to another, but it doesn't work and i don't know why.

Here's my code:

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("1VehicleMonitor").Folders("ToDo")
donebox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("1VehicleMonitor").Folders("Done")

messages = inbox.Items

message = messages.GetLast()
body_json = message.body

if message.UnRead == True:
    #do something magical
    message.UnRead = False
    message.Move(donebox)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there an error code being printed out?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not =/

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: add a bunch of print statements and get display them

Comment: @dimitry every line of code is working, except the last one where to mail item should be moved from one folder to another. After i ran the code, the mail item is visible in outlook as read, but still inside the folder "ToDo". It should be moved to the folder "Done"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OMG i've found the answer myself. I just don't get it why :D

The function have to be called outside the If clause...

```
if message.UnRead == True:
    #do something magical
    message.UnRead = False

message.Move(donebox)
```

does Python check the clause for every line of code? I've just developed some things in Java an there is the clause only checked once...

Comment: It does check just once and if true executes every line in the block. If false it executes no line in that block. Exactly like in Java.

Comment: okay then i have absolutely no clue why i have to move the line of code out of the if clause

Comment: Because it doesn't belong to the `if` but should be executed whether the mail was unread or not. You couldn't have the line as part of the `if` branch in Java either if you want to move the message independent of the `if` condition's result.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a bit more code but I think it makes sense and it works.

```
unread_messages = []

for message in messages:
    if message.Unread == True:
    unread_messages.append(message)

for message in unread_messages:
    message.Move(donebox)
```